# Does a CMP+JE consume more clock cycles than a single MUL?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, assembly, x86

I'm running an **x86** processor, but I believe my question is pretty general. I'm curious about the theoretical difference in clock cycles consumed by a `CMP + JE` sequence versus a single `MUL` operation.

In C pseudocode:

```
unsigned foo = 1;    /* must be 0 or 1 */
unsigned num = 0;

/* Method 1: CMP + JE*/
if(foo == 1){
    num = 5;
}

/* Method 2: MUL */
num = foo*5;    /* num = 0 if foo = 0 */
```

*Don't look too deeply into the pseudocode, it's purely there to illuminate the mathematical logic behind the two methods.*

What I'm actually comparing are the following two sequences of instructions:

**Method 1: CMP + JE**

```
    MOV EAX, 1    ; FOO = 1 here, but can be set to 0
    MOV EBX, 0    ; NUM = 0

    CMP EAX, 1    ; if(foo == 1)
    JE  SUCCESS   ; enter branch
    JMP FINISH    ; end program

SUCCESS:
    MOV EBX, 5    ; num = 5

FINISH:
```

**Method 2: MUL**

```
    MOV EAX, 1    ; FOO = 1 here, but can be set to 0

    MOV ECX, EAX  ; save copy of FOO to ECX
    MUL ECX, 5    ; result = foo*5
    MOV EBX, ECX  ; num = result = foo*5
```

It seems that a single `MUL` (4 total instructions) is more efficient than a `CMP + JE` (6 total instructions), but are clock cycles consumed **equally** for instructions -- i.e. is the number of clock cycles it takes to complete an instruction that same for any other instruction?

If the actual clock cycles consumed is dependent on the machine, is a single `MUL` typically faster than the branching approach on most processors, since it requires fewer total instructions?

Comment: In a case like this, a `CMOV` will likely be more efficient than either `CMP + JE` or `MUL`.

Comment: This is probably the first rule of machine code optimization.  *Always* avoid a branch if you can.  Mis-predicted branches are very expensive.  Rule number 0 is to always measure first.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a bit of an "apples to oranges" comparison - the two methods are not equivalent if `foo` is not in `{0, 1}`.

Comment: @twalberg Oops, I forgot to state that `foo` is required to be `0` or `1` for the math to hold.

Comment: The "branch" version is not likey to use `JE ` followed by `JMP` - instead it would be a single `JNE FINISH`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern CPU performance is **much** more complicated than just counting the number of cycles for each instruction.  You need to take all of the following into account (at least):

- Branch prediction
- Instruction reordering
- Register renaming
- Instruction cache hits/misses
- Data cache hits/misses
- TLB misses/page faults

All of these will be heavily influenced by the surrounding code.

So essentially, it's almost impossible to perform a micro-benchmark like this and obtain a useful result!

However, if I had to guess, I'd say that the code without the JE will be more efficient in general, as it eliminates the branch, which simplifies the branch-prediction behaviour.

Comment: So theoretically even the latency of the same instruction called twice can differ?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: In an ideal world (i.e. assuming no stalling, etc.), the number of cycles the core takes to execute a given instruction is deterministic.  But all of the effects above will dominate throughput in practice.

Comment: IMO, you should add a bullet for data cache misses + bus waits. (and maybe even page faults and context switches) Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, on a modern x86 processor, both the `CMP` and the `MUL` instruction will occupy an integer execution unit for one cycle (`CMP` is essentially a `SUB` that throws away the result and just modifies the flags register).  However, modern x86 processors are also pipelined, superscalar and out-of-order, which means that the performance depends on more than just this underlying cycle cost alone.

If the branch cannot be predicted well, then the branch misprediction penalty will swamp other factors and the `MUL` version will perform significantly better.

On the other hand, if the branch *can* be well predicted *and* you immediately use `num` in a subsequent calculation, then it's possible for the branching version to perform better in the average case.  That's because when it correctly predicts the branch, it can start speculatively executing the next instruction using the predicted value of `num`, before the result of the compare is available (whereas in the `MUL` case, subsequent use of `num` will have a data dependency on the result of the `MUL` - it won't be able to execute until that result is retired).